# How to precisely move origin without having a solid point to snap

Tags: snapping, origin, stl

I have this object:

[image]

[image]

[image]

and I want to place its origin centered in XY and to the lower position in Z.
Using the predefined positions (i.e. center mass/volume) does not work for obvious reasons).

I'm able to directly move the origin using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> but my difficulties are about how to "snap" the origin without having something to snap to.

Would you please to guide me, how to position it?
I'm using Blender 3.6.0 under Ubuntu 22.10 and the model is an imported STL.
I want to place the origin there so I can easily position the model related to the other objects.

### UPDATE

To be more clear, the object is imported from STL, so it's geometry is not simple:

[image]

Comment: create another mesh, duplicating and separating a part of your object, then use it to snap the cursor then the object origin where you need to. In this case, the part to separate should be the largest circle around your mesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get along with pie menus, it would be worth checking out the shipped add-on: 'Interface: 3D Viewport Pie Menus'. One of its features is an 'Origin' pie menu, which includes 'Origin to Bottom':

[image]

You still have to be on the lookout for your Pivot Point, as you do with conventional centering, or snapping the 3D cursor 'To Geometry'.

The snaps respect the pivot setting. If your pivot is set to *Bounding Box Center*, (which is what you appear to want here,) that's a different thing from *Median Point*, which will be weighted to the median location of your vertices.

Comment: Great! I didn't know this addon.

Answer (score 2):

To correctly align on X and Y, select one of the top circular edge loops, put the 3D cursor to the selection...

[image]

Then put the origin to the 3D cursor:

[image]

To correctly align on Z, enable the *Transform Affect Only Origins* option:

[image]

Move the origin down and snap to a bottom vertex. Once done, disable the *Transform Affect Only Origins* option:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I can follow these suggestion. As I wrote in my question, it is an imported STL (I've added right now a view in Edit Mode). I'm not able to select the edge loop, like I do with "native" geometries.

Comment: This is actually not a very messy geometry, you can search for Tris to Quads function to get tidy loops on the object. You may need to make sure the triangles are not separate by merging by distance(M->B in edit mode) first. you could also select 2 vertices on the opposite sides of the circle, or use Origin to Geometry operator in Bounds Center mode to center on XY axis and snap to bottom with grab operation in Affect Only Origins mode. There are many more ways to do it, it's hard to know what is best.